# Access a piece of code in more activities?

Tags: java, android, listview, popup, popupwindow

I have a `ListPopupWindow` with a couple of items which acts as a menu (more options) but i have 3 different activities and i have to copy paste the whole `ListPopupWindow` code in all activities.

What i want to achieve is to have the `ListPopupWindow` only in one class and to be able to open it everywhere i like. How can it be done?

I tried with `static` but haven't got so far i am out of ideas..

[image: Ex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new base activity containing your `ListPopupWindow` that your other activitis inherit from.

```
Activity1 extends BaseActivity 
Activity2 extends BaseActivity
```

etc. so that your activities can access that code. If you are new to Java, inheritance and the extends keyword are worth researching.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :) Best of luck!